# Matching DateObject with Cases

Tags: pattern-matching, filtering, date-and-time

OK, here is something that is me missing the obvious.

I have an Excel spreadsheet consisting of 2 columns and 5 rows.  The first column is formatted in Excel as a dd-mmm-yy date.  The second column is a string.

I import the file into Mathematica:

```
testData = Flatten[Import["testData.xlsx","Data"],1]
```

[image]

I want to use Cases to select the rows that belong to September 3:

```
myDate = DateObject[{2017,9,3,0,0,0}]
```

[image]

```
Cases[testData,{myDate,_}]
```

but this gives as output:

```
{}
```

What am I missing?  Thanks much in advance.

Comment: The proper `DateObject` probably has a lot of meta-info tagged onto it. Extract one of them and look at its `FullForm` and use the pattern you derive from that for you `myDate`. My guess is you'll want to do something like `DateObject[{2017, 9, 3, ___}, ___]`

Comment: Thank you for your help. There is indeed metadata: DateObject[{2017,9,3,0,0,0],"Instant","Gregorian",-7.`]

Comment: I mean `myDate` probably captured some of that. I dunno if it would have captured all, though. Did this pattern work: `DateObject[{2017, 9, 3, ___}, ___]`?

Comment: Yes I got it to work.

Comment: Great. Post what you did as an answer so people know this has been dealt with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`DateWithinQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateWithinQ.html) with a [`DateObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateObject.html) of `"Day"` calendar granularity within [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html).

With

```
testData = Transpose[{DateObject@DateRange[{2017, 08, 31}, {2017, 9, 4}, "Day"], Range[5]}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

and

```
targetDate = DateObject[{2017, 9, 3}, "Day"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice that `targetDate` is of `"Day"` granularity.

Then

```
Select[DateWithinQ[targetDate, First@#] &]@testData
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Since `targetDate` is of `"Day"` granularity any `DateObject` within the day (i.e. all dates of the day at any time within the day) with match in `DateWithinQ`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The situation is reminiscent of picking out rows that contain inexact numbers with a predicate that depends on equality, where using `Cases[]` is clunky, and `Select[]` is the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

As b3m2a1 points out, there is a lot of metadata tacked on to DateObjects, see my comment above.

```
Cases[testData,{DateObject[{2017,9,3,___},___],_}]
```

works.

Comment: There's a simpler solution. Use `myDate = DateObject[{2017, 9, 3, 0, 0, 0.}]` note the seconds value has a _decimal point_. With this change, your original `Cases` works for me.

Comment: Yes this works too.  Thank you